# Python proxy class with type hints

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a class Model that inherits from a Protocol to define its interface as follows:

```py
class _ModelInterface(Protocol):
    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        ...

class Model(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, ...): # Stuff to init
        ...

    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        ... # performs predictions and returns
```

At some point I decided to create a proxy class called ModelClient using attribute proxy:

```py
class ModelClient(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, ref: str):
        # performs some stuff to get a Model from ref
        self.model = Model(...)

    def __getattr__(self, attr: str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self.model, attr)
```

With the above approach I get type hints and autocompletion for the ModelClient, and also I can have an explicit hint of the ModelClient class beeing compliant with the interface _ModelInterface. The problem is that **gettattr** is accessing the attributes inherited from the Protocol class instead of the self.model ones.
If I drop the inheritance for _ModelInterface in the ModelClient the proxy class works properly, but lacks the 'interface definition' (so it's actual interface is not explicit).

Is there a way to keep the attribute proxy and maintain an explicit hint for the interface of the proxy class?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question! The thing is about Protocols is that they assert that all methods must be implemented by the child class, and cannot detect anything that's happening inside getattr. The way I see it there are three solutions to this:

### 1. Don't use protocols, but describe the interface in another way

If we remove the constraint that specifically Protocol is required this restriction goes away. We can describe the interface without adding the restriction that all these methods must be implemented by the child class:

```py
from typing import Any

class _ModelInterface:
    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Model(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, name: str): # Stuff to init
        self.name = name

    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        return input

exclusions = ['model']
class ModelClient(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, ref: str):
        # performs some stuff to get a Model from ref
        self.model = Model(ref)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str) -> Any:
        if attr in exclusions:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        else:
            return self.model.__getattribute__(attr)

out = ModelClient('test')
```

### 2. Separate the protocol and the interface

If you **really** need the methods to be asserted as being implemented, depending on the number of methods, you could make a protocol and non-protocol interface. It's been talked about that it would be nice if there were a way to derive protocols from classes, but current there isn't a way:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol

class _ModelInterface:
    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        ...
class _ModelProtocol(Protocol):
    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        ...

class Model(_ModelProtocol):
    def __init__(self, name: str): # Stuff to init
        self.name = name

    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        return input

exclusions = ['model']
class ModelClient(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, ref: str):
        # performs some stuff to get a Model from ref
        self.model = Model(ref)

    def __getattribute__(self, attr: str) -> Any:
        if attr in exclusions:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        else:
            return self.model.__getattribute__(attr)

out = ModelClient('test')
out.predict('out')
```

Not ideal, but now Model must implement all the methods in the protocol.

### 3. Implement the methods

Protocol says that the methods must be implemented, so you can just implement them:

```py
from typing import Protocol


class _ModelInterface(Protocol):
    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        ...

class Model(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, name: str): # Stuff to init
        self.name = name

    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        return input

class ModelClient(_ModelInterface):
    def __init__(self, ref: str):
        # performs some stuff to get a Model from ref
        self.model = Model(ref)

    def predict(self, input: str) -> str:
        return self.model.predict(input)

out = ModelClient('test')
out.predict('new')
```

Comment: The 3rd method is what I am trying to avoid, exlicitly defining all methods. The other two methods do not behave as expected: when calling a method in ModelClient __getattr__ finds that is defined in _ModelInterface. What I exactly want is a way to tell __getattr__ that it has to look up the attributes in self.model, not the default ones inherited from _ModelInterface.

Comment: I was assuming the interface of _ModelInterface matches the interface of ModelClient - is this not the case? Does Model add additional attributes and methods?

Comment: Ah I follow you since the `__init__` methods are different

Comment: @Dioni Ok - so you want something that has all the methods and attributes of `Model` - how is it any different from something that inherits from `Model`?

Comment: I want the ModelClient to implement the interface, not directly but by calling the attributes of its self.model attribute. If I inherit directly from Model (not from the interface) when I replace Model with another class that implements the same interface I will have to change the inherited class also.

Comment: Yeah ok this makes sense - however to initialise the model in the "performs some stuff to get a Model from ref" there must be some consistency between the `__init__` of different Model classes. Can you describe in more detail what this step is? Also in your example it uses specifically `Model` in `ModelClient`, so at the moment you can't replace Model with another class.

Comment: Actually ModelClient initializes self.client by calling a function load_model. The point is that self.client follows the interface, and by mapping the methods of ModelClient to its self.model, so does the ModelClient, but that is not explicit, which is what I want

Comment: Apologies, I realise now there was a bug in my original solution for methods 1 and 2 - I've now updated so that it gets the right attribute